# Combobox selection sequence for images

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox

I'm a little noobish so sorry if this is really simple...

I have ~120 pictures and I would like to be able to select and display one of those pictures when the name in the combobox corresponds to that picture. I would like to know how to populate the combobox with the name of each picture and select a picture from the box without making 120 "if" statements? Each image has it's own filename in the project.Properties.Resources folder

Also, if there's a way to rename 120 pictures really quickly, that would save me a lot of time but it's fine if i just have to do it by hand.

The form is WPF and I'm using Visual studio 2012 Express

Comment: is it winforms or web?

Comment: You still need to provide a little more info...how are you storing both the names and the images they correspond to? Are the names filenames in the file system? Are they mapped to the images via a dictionary? Or do you have a model class containing both a string and bitmap object?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `Model` to hold your image data and populate a `ObservableCollection<T>` of that model, Then we can bind that collection to the `ComboBox` and set the `ComboBox` selectedItem to a `Image` control

Here is an example:

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication14
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyImage> _images = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>();
        private MyImage _selectedImage;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             // Add image files to collection
            foreach (var image in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\your image directory"))
            {
                // set name and path in model
                Images.Add(new MyImage { Path = image, Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image) });
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Images
        {
            get { return _images; }
            set { _images = value; }
        }

        public MyImage SelectedImage
        {
            get { return _selectedImage; }
            set { _selectedImage = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedImage"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyImage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBlock Text="Images" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Selected Image" />
        <Image Source="{Binding SelectedImage.Path}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well `WPF` memories are really rusty but as a generalization, you need to know where the selected image in in List. What you can do is keep track of index/positoin of each image in list in a dictionary:

```
private imageIndices=new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

store indices:

```
imageIndices[<IMAGE_NAME>] = <INDEX_OF_IMAGE>;
```

get name of image from dropdown and get where that image is from dictionary:

```
var n=<IMAGE_NAME>;

list.Select(imageIndices[<IMAGE_NAME>]);//use actual method name to select
```